# Filter prometheus gauge metrics by value range

Tags: time-series, prometheus, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

Prometheus does support binary comparison operators between an instant vector and a scalar. E.g. `memory_usage_bytes > 1024`. But is it possible to query a gauge metric that is greater than X and smaller than Y at the same time? How can I achieve something like `memory_usage_bytes > 1024 && <= 2048`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I think I figured it out. A query like this would return metrics within a value range:

```
(go_gc_duration_seconds > 0.0002) < 0.0006
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
memory_usage_bytes > 1024 and memory_usage_bytes <= 2048
```

Comment: I think it'll work. But technically it's two vectors combined, isn't it? Doesn't look completely fair.

Comment: Yes, it's an intersection of two vectors. It's fair enough, you don't have another option anyway.

Comment: I think I found an alternative solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/67522754/1201488.